# Sending Attachments /w JavaMail Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, email, jakarta-mail

I have very little knowledge with Java and working with Android. I have been trying to create a very simple Android App that will send before/after pictures as an attachment. It was pretty simple setting up what I already have, however I have had a lot of issues in regards to adding attachments to my emails. After messing with the code for hours erasing and restarting multiple times, I thought it would just be best to ask for some help.

Here is all that I currently have, it is sending emails all correctly. I am just not understanding how to incorporate an intent for the user to select an image from gallery and then using their selection with JavaMail to actually be attached with the email.

Thanks :)

**MAINACTIVITY.JAVA**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner email;
private EditText subject, message;
private Button btn;


Button beforeAttachment;
Button afterAttachment;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    subject = findViewById(R.id.subject);
    message = findViewById(R.id.message);
    beforeAttachment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.beforeAttachment);
    afterAttachment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.afterAttachment);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);


    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    email.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    //attachment button listener
    beforeAttachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPickPhoto(v);
        }
    });


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            senEmail();
        }
    });


}

//Attachment--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Trigger gallery selection for a photo
public void onPickPhoto(View view) {
    // Create intent for picking a photo from the gallery
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void senEmail() {
    try {
        String mEmail = email.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String mSubject = subject.getText().toString();
        String mMessage = message.getText().toString();

        JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(this, mEmail, mSubject, mMessage);

        javaMailAPI.execute();
    }

    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed try again: " + t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

**JAVAMAILAPI.java**

```
ublic class JavaMailAPI extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private Context context;

private Session session;
private String email, subject, message;


private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public JavaMailAPI(Context context, String email, String subject, String message) {
    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;

}

//Execute progress Dialog
@Override
protected  void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Sending message", "Please wait...",false,false);
}

//Execution notification
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //Dismissing the progress dialog
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


//API/SMTP Information
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    //Authentication (Utils)
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(Utils.EMAIL, Utils.PASSWORD);

        }
    });

    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {


        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Utils.EMAIL));
        mimeMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, String.valueOf(new InternetAddress(email)));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mimeMessage.setText(message);

        Transport.send(mimeMessage);


        System.out.println("Message sent!");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return null;

}
```

}

**UTILS.java**

```
public class Utils {
//This is the FROM email
public static final String EMAIL = "";
//This is the FROM email PASSWORD
public static final String PASSWORD = "";}
```